# django changelist_view and changeform_view customizing

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to substitute default `select <model> to change` writing in django changelist view with my custom one?

Same question about `change <model>` in change form.

I've been searching both change_form.html and change_list.html (also base_site.html and base.html) for this expression, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the admin; this string seems to be set in `django.contrib.admin.views.main.ChangeList.__init__`:

```
    # ...
    if self.is_popup:
        title = ugettext('Select %s')
    else:
        title = ugettext('Select %s to change')
    self.title = title % force_text(self.opts.verbose_name)
    # ...
```

You could create a ChangeList subclass like this:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList
class NewTitleChangeList(ChangeList):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewTitleChangeList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title = "<New Title Here>"

class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return NewTitleChangeList
```